# React - Accessing Ref for Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and am trying to create an image sliding carousel (something like this: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). I have my CSS in place where the images are tiled horizontally, and I am trying to make the images scroll horizontally when the Previous and Next carousel navigation buttons are pressed.

My solution is to attach a `ref` via JSX to my `.carousel__viewport` object, and use `this.refs.viewport.scrollLeft` to move the carousel. When I do click on the carousel navigation buttons, I do see the `console.log()` returning with `undefined` and the viewport is not scrolling. When inspecting my app with the Chrome debugger, I have highlighted the `.carousel__viewport` element and verified that `$0.leftScroll = 150;` does indeed scroll the images horizontally.

What should I be doing to be able to scroll the viewport by X amount of pixels?

```
// carousel.js

'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Slide = require('./slide');

class Carousel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    renderSlide(image, index) {
        return (
            <Slide key={index} image={image} />
        );
    };

    navClick(direction) {
        console.log(this.viewport);
        this.viewport.scrollLeft = 150; // carousel viewport not scrolling       
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="carousel">
                <div className="carousel__viewport" ref={r => this.viewport = r}>
                    {this.props.images.map(this.renderSlide)}
                </div>

                <span className="carousel__previous" onClick={() => this.navClick('left')}>Previous</span>
                <br />
                <span className="carousel__next" onClick={() => this.navClick('right')}>Next</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

Carousel.propTypes = {
    images: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

module.exports = Carousel;

-----    

/* carousel.less */
.carousel {
  width: 100%;

  &__viewport {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the ref correctly. Using [strings as ref is legacy support](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) and should not be used as it's likely to be removed.

You can set the ref like this:

```
<div className="carousel__viewport" ref={r => this.viewport = r}>
```

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggested and am accessing the ref by `this.viewport.scrollLeft = 150;` but I still don't see the carousel scrolling. I have updated my code in my post to reflect these changes.